# Switching AngularJS views while waiting for promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, view, promise

I have the following code (see below) where **MyCtrl1** is a controller of a view that the app is routed to depending on URL. The controller calls a function in a models service which returns a promise from an http request. The model is supposed to log something in another service **responseService**, based on response and return promise to controller. If the http response takes a while I need the user to be able to switch views through the URL and still having the model working on request until it is done. here are my questions:

If the user switches view in the middle of the http request:

1. the **MyCtrl1** is gone, i.e. the next time user switches back to
   the **MyCtrl1** view it would not *remember* the call and the
   promise would not be returned to it, correct?
2. Is the model service still be working on http request and update
   **responseService** when response is received?
3. If the latter is "no", the how can I make it work? I need the user
   to be able to switch views while the http is working.

Thanks!

myctrl1.controller.js:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', 'myModels', function ($scope, myModels) {

    myModels.listMyData().then(
        function(response) {
            ...
        },
        function(response) {
            ...
        }
    );
}]);
```

myModels.models.js:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .service('myModels', ['$http', '$q', 'responseService', function($http, $q, responseService) {

    this.listMyData = function() {

        var promise;
        ...

        $http.get('http://xxx.xxx.xxx').then(
            function(response) {
               // register something in responseService
               // assign promise
            },
            function(response) {
               // register something in responseService
               // assign promise
            }
        );

        return promise;   
    }

}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say that objects/functions in javascript are deleted only if they are not referenced. When you call:

```
$http.post(...).then(callback)
```

`callback` function is now referenced. So it wont be deleted and it will execute disregarding if user switches view.
Answering your questions:
1. Yes
2. Yes